# Zend Framework autoloading classes extended by models

Tags: zend-framework

I'm new to zend framework so maybe this question is stupid..

I've got a default hierarchy

site
|--bootstrap.php
|--application
|--models
   |-- Item.php
   |-- ModelAbstract.php
|--...

Inside Item.php there's

```
<?php
    //TODO: trying to remove this require...
    require_once('ModelAbstract.php');

    class CF_Model_Flower extends CF_Model_Abstract
    {
      ...
```

Inside 'ModelAbstract.php' there's

```
<?php

    class CF_Model_Abstract
    {
     ...
```

And my application Bootstrap.php looks like

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'CF',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }
  ...
```

If I removed the 'require_once' inside Item.php I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'CF_Model_Abstract' not found in /Mysite/application/models/Item.php on line 6
```

Why ? And how can I use autoloading to live without this require_once ?

In fact, renaming 'ModelAbstract.php' to 'Abstract.php' works. Can someone explain me why ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` and such. But if they work anything like earlier ZF autoloading mechanisms, the autoloader will look for class CF_Model_Abstract in:

`CF/Model/Abstract.php`

or maybe with this namespace/basePath configuration in:

`models/Model/Abstract.php`

or:

`models/CF/Model/Abstract.php`

but probably not in:

`models/ModelAbstract.php`

So in other words, the underscores represent child directories.

Comment: You gave me a serious hint, I've just renamed 'ModelAbstract.php' to 'Abstract.php' and it worked !  

I just can't figure out why :-/  
I thought namespaces where used to prefix classes the Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader checked from 'basePath' some default ressources, ie in 'models' directory it would search classes like "CF_Model_XXX". I thought filenames where meaningless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the _ in the namespace.

```
 $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'CF_',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your bootstrap file:

```
protected function _initAutoLoad()
{
    $loader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => 'CF',
    ));

    $loader->addResourceType('form', 'forms', 'Form')
        ->addResourceType('model', 'models', 'Model')
        ->addResourceType('mapper', 'models/mappers', 'Model_Mapper')
        ->addResourceType('dbtable', 'models/DbTable', 'Model_DbTable');
    return $loader;
}
```

This will load models, forms, dbtables, and mappers for you. Hope this does the trick.